# My TV supposedly doesn’t have VESA mounting support, but I want to mount it. Any ideas?

Tags: mounting, television

I’ve found an option when searching for my exact model of tv (50” Samsung UN50ES6900F), but it’s a very basic mount that doesn’t do what I want and it costs more money. [link.](https://a.co/d/gbDg0tb)

I was hoping to get something a little cheaper with further extension from the wall and the additional horizontal panning option, like [this.](https://a.co/d/3dBd0y2)

They look mostly the same to me, and I’m not sure why the TV isn’t VESA certified. Is there any reason NOT to just get the one I want? Will it really not work? I’m confused.

Comment: Just because some random online store listing says "for your TV" does not mean it will actually work. It could be a mistake or a lie. If you want a better answer, post a picture of the back of your TV. Ideally with a tape measure for scale.

Comment: Most larger TVs *are* vesa compatible or will work with a universal wall mount. The stock feet are junk because no one really uses them

Answer (score 3):

You can just make an adapter template out of 3/4 plywood.

You make one side of your plywood fit your tv back and the other side hook into the vesa mount.  If the hole spacing overlaps you offset the template but you'll need to be careful to have the center of gravity relative to the mount reasonable.

I used a scrap piece of 3/4 plywood to make a french cleat and secured one of the cleats to the wall and the other to a piece of plywood that used the vesa mount holes using m4 bolts - not the most impressive looking but cheap and works great.

[image: french cleat plywood vesa mount]

Comment: Installing a TV on plywood might not be really fire-hazard safe. (Yes, TVs can overheat...)  When I faced a similar issue (wrong sized VESA and stuff), I used perforated metal bars screwed together.

Comment: I highly doubt plywood is a fire hazard, given that the ignition temperature of wood is in the >400ºF range.  Even considering the glue in plywood, probably.

Comment: If the TV ignites the plywood, your problem is that the TV is on fire.